# Image selected in thumbnail what image current in view pager. it Only work for 4 images

Tags: android, android-layout

Activity class:

```
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager myPager;
    ImageButton leftBtn, rightBtn;
    RecyclerView myList;
    private List<String> _images;
    GalleryPagerAdapter _adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        leftBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.left_nav);
        rightBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.right_nav);
        myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewFrag);
        _images = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.user_photos));
        Assert.assertNotNull(_images);
        _adapter = new GalleryPagerAdapter(this);
        myPager.setAdapter(_adapter);

        myPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4); // how many images to load into memory
        _adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        HorizontalAdapter horizontalAdapter = new HorizontalAdapter(_images);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer
                = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        myList.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);
        myList.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);
        horizontalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        leftBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int tab = myPager.getCurrentItem();
                if (tab > 0) {
                    tab--;
                    myPager.setCurrentItem(tab);
                } else if (tab == 0) {
                    myPager.setCurrentItem(tab);
                }
            }
        });

        // Images right navigatin
        rightBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int tab = myPager.getCurrentItem();
                tab++;
                myPager.setCurrentItem(tab);
            }
        });
        // MenuScroll.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);

         myPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                myList.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                LinearLayout llSelect;
                for (int i = 0; i < _images.size(); i++) {
                    llSelect = ((LinearLayout) myList.getChildAt(i));
                    if (i == position) {
                        llSelect.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3fa9f5"));
                    } else {
                        llSelect.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                    }
                    myList.scrollToPosition(position);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class GalleryPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        Context _context;
        LayoutInflater _inflater;

        GalleryPagerAdapter(Context context) {
            _context = context;
            _inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return _images.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
            View itemView = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_gallery_item, container, false);
            container.addView(itemView);

            // Get the border size to show around each image
            //int borderSize = _thumbnails.getPaddingTop();          

            final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 260);
            params.setMargins(3, 3, 3, 3);

            final ImageView thumbView = new ImageView(_context);
            thumbView.setTag(position);
            thumbView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            thumbView.setLayoutParams(params);
            thumbView.setMinimumHeight(260);

            thumbView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                   /* for (int j=0;j<_thumbnails.getChildCount();j++)
                    {
                        if (_thumbnails.getChildAt(j).getBackground()!=null) {
                            _thumbnails.getChildAt(j).setBackground(null);
                        }
                    }

                    Drawable highlight = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.border);
                    _thumbnails.getChildAt(position).setPadding(4,4,4,4);
                    _thumbnails.getChildAt(position).setBackground(highlight);*/
                    myPager.setCurrentItem(position);

                }
            });



            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);


            Glide.with(ScrollingActivity.this).load("" + _images.get(position))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .into(imageView);

            imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));

            return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
        }
    }

    private class OnImageClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        int myPostion;

        // constructor
        OnImageClickListener(int position) {
            this.myPostion = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(_images);

        }
    }

    class HorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        private List<String> horizontalList;

        class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            ImageView imgCards;

            MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                imgCards = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
            }
        }

        HorizontalAdapter(List<String> horizontalList) {
            this.horizontalList = horizontalList;
        }

        @Override
        public HorizontalAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.layout_thumb_image, parent, false);


            return new HorizontalAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final HorizontalAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            Glide.with(ScrollingActivity.this).load("" + horizontalList.get(position))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .into(holder.imgCards);

            holder.imgCards.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return horizontalList.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Layout File:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:background="@drawable/placeholder"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/left_nav"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="#80ffffff"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/right_nav"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#80ffffff"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/left_nav"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewFrag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thumb layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llSelect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
</LinearLayout>
```

pager_gallery_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[work for only 4 thumb`` images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHHc3.png)

I need to whatever image display in pager view relevant image selected border in Thumb view image.

ViewPager and RecycleView for Image Swipe(viewPager) Thumbnail of image(RecycleView). i show ThumbImage selected when relevant image is shown.

Comment: more then 4 image java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Change the setOffscreenPageLimit from 4 to _images.size()

Comment: hey are you here? I will write code if you still can not find a solution

Comment: @jignesh yes, fnd i also try this. but still have same issue.

Comment: @propoLis no friend i still not find the solution for that. Please help.

Comment: ok please share your pager_gallery_item

Comment: @propoLis : I edit the post and Add Missing file.

Answer (score 0):

Only you can remove linearLayout backgroundColor from viewPager onPageSelected. You should add these lines to adapter like this:

```
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                myList.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
//               LinearLayout llSelect;
                for (int i = 0; i < _images.size(); i++) {
//                    llSelect = ((LinearLayout) myList.getChildAt(i));
//                    if (i == position) {
//                        llSelect.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3fa9f5"));
//                    } else {
//                        llSelect.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
//                    }
                    myList.scrollToPosition(position);
                }
            }
```

Your ViewPagerAdapter:

```
private class GalleryPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        Context _context;
        LayoutInflater _inflater;

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        View itemView = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_gallery_item, container, false);
            container.addView(itemView);

        ////////////////////////You can add unSelected background color in line      
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

        // Get the border size to show around each image       

        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 260);
        params.setMargins(3, 3, 3, 3);

        final ImageView thumbView = new ImageView(_context);
        thumbView.setTag(position);
        thumbView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        thumbView.setLayoutParams(params);
        thumbView.setMinimumHeight(260);

        thumbView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             ////////////////////////You can add selected background color in line      
             itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3fa9f5"));
             myPager.setCurrentItem(position);

            }
        });



        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);


        Glide.with(ScrollingActivity.this).load("" + _images.get(position))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(imageView);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));

        return itemView;
        }
```

Comment: Dear @ propoLis code is not much beneficial.  i want this https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHHc3.png  whatever image currently display in main view that relevant thumb image select only. In my code it work but only for 4 images.

Comment: when i add more then 4 images to _image then it gives the error :  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Ok I fixed some of the code and only working your user_photos size probably.

Comment: you have not explicitly mistaken the code in this way, I've understand your crash when I implemented code.

Comment: ok thanks @propoLis to give your time. you have any Alternative or any suggestion to perform this. ?